# How to disable pagination in sense plugin while query elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I'm using elastic search for making global search for that I'm using sense plugin for poc but while I'm hitting my query with sense I get paginated data but I want all data in a single query.

```
            GET /_search?q=2016
```

My result is this:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 21,
    "successful": 21,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 465,
    "max_score": 0.3500354,
    "hits":[
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Elasticsearch returns 10 documents per request. You can use the 'size' param to retrieve more products with one query, like:

```
GET /_search?q=2016&size=465
```

Note that there is a limit on the max results per request (defaults to 10.000), as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)